# Blazor WebAssembly JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync - blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using the drawio-integration project in my Blazor WebAssembly app.

https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-integration

The simple helloworld sample looks like this:

```
<img onclick='DiagramEditor.editElement(this);' src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

http://jgraph.github.io/drawio-integration/helloworld.html

https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-integration/blob/master/helloworld.html

If I run the code like this everything works without a console error:

```
<img onclick='DiagramEditor.editElement(this);' @ref=MyImageElementReference src="@DrawIoImageDataUrl" style="cursor:pointer;">

ElementReference MyImageElementReference;
```

If I run the code like this everything works as well but I get a console error.

```
<img @onclick="TriggerClick" @ref=MyImageElementReference src="@DrawIoImageDataUrl" style="cursor:pointer;">

ElementReference MyImageElementReference;

public async Task TriggerClick()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("DiagramEditor.editElement", MyImageElementReference);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ijsruntime

What is causing the error below and what can I do to prevent it?

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting
> circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLImageElement'
> |     property '_blazorEvents_1' -> object with constructor 'e'
> |     property 'handlers' -> object with constructor 'Object'
> |     property 'click' -> object with constructor 'Object'
> --- property 'element' closes the circle
> at JSON.stringify ()
> at blazor.webassembly.js:1

Comment: Does it throws the error on the click or while loading?

Comment: @Alamakanambra on click

Answer (score 1):

So I have the same problem. By further inspection InvokeAsyn returns a `ValueTask` and not a `Task`.

So if you make you method return a `ValueTask` instead of a `Task` it might sove the issue but then you just need to find a way to convert your button to that type which I couldn't figure out.

Let me know if it works and how you covered it.